# Programatically send SMS (Not getting delivery status)

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically send SMS Android (Not receiving status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701254/programatically-send-sms-android-not-receiving-status)

I am using [this code example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) word for word except for the fact that I changed

```
   import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
```

to

```
   import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

The SMS is sending fine however I am not getting the TOAST message that it was delivered (sent to the network).  I am trying to integrate SMS into my application and this is important.  I am sure this can be done because how else would the stock SMS app know when to stop displaying the "sending circle".  The relevant code section is as follows:

```
    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

I am using a Jelly Bean ROM but I believe I tested this same segment a while ago on Gingerbread and ICS with the same results.  Has the API changed or is there an issue with the sample?  I am testing on a Sasmsung GSIII if that helps.  My old tests were on an Epic.

Comment: Do a Log.d inside the onReceive() method and see if or what value you are getting for getResultCode()

Answer (score 2):

Using a Toast to test can confuse things since depending on the situation the Toast notification may not be raised. Try changing it to a Log call or use a debugger to see if that part gets called at all.