# Programatically send SMS Android (Not receiving status)

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am using http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android code example word for word except for the fact that I changed:

```
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
```

to:

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

The SMS is sending fine however I am not getting the TOAST message that it was delivered (sent to the network). I am trying to integrate SMS into my application and this is important. I am sure this can be done because how else would the stock SMS app know when to stop displaying the "sending circle". The relevant code section is as follows:

```
   //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

I am using a Jelly Bean ROM but I believe I tested this same segment a while ago on Gingerbread and ICS with the same results. Has the API changed or is there an issue with the sample? I am testing on a Sasmsung GSIII if that helps. My old tests were on an Epic.

Comment: Did you install Go SMS or some thing like that?

Comment: Nope.  Currently I'm using the stock ASOP SMS app (running CyannogenMod) but tested on other ROMs in the bast.  I do not see any Intents in ADB logcat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically send SMS (Not getting delivery status)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701215/programatically-send-sms-not-getting-delivery-status)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this problem now, if you're testing this on Android 4.4 or later, it will not work unless your app is the default SMS app.

From the docs -

> > Beginning with Android 4.4, the system settings allow users to select a "default SMS app." Once selected, only the default SMS app is able to write to the SMS Provider and only the default SMS app receives the SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an SMS or the WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an MMS. The default SMS app is responsible for writing details to the SMS Provider when it receives or sends a new message.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS).

Answer (score 0):

Your code look pretty good to do. Maybe the problem is that your carrier does not provide you the delivery reports( there may be an option to subscribe to a service) or you have not turned on delivery reports in your mobile. There is  helpful app on the play store called Delivery Reports from which you can see the status of each sms.